# Multiline assignment in es2015

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm just beginning to learn React and trying to figure out some patterns. Is there a way to do something like this without using a function:

```
const myElement =
 <MyComponent>
    <ChildComponent />
 </MyComponent>

return (
  <div>
    {this.state.open ? myElement : otherElement}
  </div>
);
```

I realize I can assign it all to one line, but that's not desirable. 
It also doesn't seem worth it to me to create a new component just for a few lines, especially if it's not going to be used elsewhere.

Edit:
Some may be wondering why not just use a function? I'm thinking there may be a performance advantage in not using a function. Maybe there isn't?

Comment: "I'm thinking there may be a performance advantage in not using a function" --- and this guess is based on ... what?

Comment: Based on assumption. :) I was hoping someone would answer that too.

Comment: @zerkms - As you said, it was just a guess.

Comment: And you never guess about performance. Before you even try to think about optimising something - you must have a reliable baseline. Unless you have it - everything you do makes no sense.

Comment: Please clarify your question -- I don't understand what you're asking. You can only `return` from a function. Instead of `return` you could assign that to a variable and then do something with that. I can't tell what the context for this is. Also, a component is where state lives.

Comment: @JMM "Instead of return you could assign that to a variable and then do something with that" -- My question is how do you assign it to a variable when it involves multiple lines. It seems the answer is you can't. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @dardub, ah I think I have misunderstood your request, I will amend my answer.

Comment: Did you actually try what you have? It should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap expressions in braces which JSX can transform into a function to build your DOM.

```
render() {
  const myElement = (
    <MyComponent>
      <ChildComponent>
    <MyComponent>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.open ? myElement : <span>Closed</span> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's often worth restructuring so that `myElement` becomes a proper component rather than just a fragment.

Comment: It's an expression, not a statement.